# How to access an element in a JSON array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

[I have a JSON array that contains some values,How can i retrieve the IsDefault value from this array.][1]
I have tried `userDefaultPagePreference[0].Isdefault` but i am getting isDefault Undefined

```
 Object
    userDefaultPagePreference : Array(1)
    0 :
    date: "2018-04-17T15:48:42.66"
    defaultUrl: null
    error: []
    id:3
    isDefault:true
    pageName: "ChangeMyAccountSettings"
    userId: "e8dfee00-6224-4a29-851e-7c10343eba9a"
```

Comment: `userDefaultPagePreference[0].isDefault` with `u` in lowercase and `D` uppercase

Comment: no, you have an object (unnamed) with a property (`userDefaultPagePreference`) that is an Array ... not a JSON Array ... `UserDefaultPagePreference` is not the same as `userDefaultPagePreference` ... plus `userDefaultPagePreference` is a property of some (unnamed by your image) object ... so it would be `someobject.userDefaultPagePreference[0].isDefault` ... note, not `.IsDefault` ... it's `.isDefault` ... javascript is **case sensitive**

Comment: also `but that is not working` contains absolutely no information ... what happens when you tried that? clearly you know what a **developer** tools console is, so you must be getting some sort of error? or is the result `undefined`

Comment: Its asynchronous call. Inside of subscription put curly brackets after arrow operator and try to console.log it there

Comment: Show your exact code for accessing the value

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable like this

```
    let userDefaultPagePreference: any[1] = [{
        0: null,
        date: "2018-04-17T15:48:42.66",
        defaultUrl: null,
        error: [],
        id: 3,
        isDefault: true,
        pageName: "ChangeMyAccountSettings",
        userId: "e8dfee00-6224-4a29-851e-7c10343eba9a"
    }];
```

**And Test `userDefaultPagePreference[0].isDefault` like this**

```
    console.log(userDefaultPagePreference[0].isDefault)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :**

- You are trying to access `Isdefault` but it should be `isDefault`.

**DEMO**

```js
var obj = {
 "userDefaultPagePreference": [{
  "date": "2018-04-17T15:48:42.66",
  "defaultUrl": null,
  "error": [],
  "id": 3,
  "isDefault": true,
  "pageName": "ChangeMyAccountSettings",
  "userId": "e8dfee00-6224-4a29-851e-7c10343eba9a"
 }]
};

console.log(obj.userDefaultPagePreference[0].isDefault);
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing an element in a JSON array in typescript here will be like this:

```
userDefaultPagePreference[0]['Isdefault']
```